# Renewing Cookie-session for express.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm using the [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) module for Expresss.js to deal with sessions.

I would like the sessions to be renewed on every page load (or ajax call). That's how they usually work anywhere.

**The documentation doesn't say a word about it.**

I've tried doing this, but without success:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next ){
     req.sessionOptions.maxAge = 20*1000;
     return next();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you are not sending the response cookie to the client. I solved the same problem (using express and cookie-session) with a middleware that sends a cookie containing a different value for each get:

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session') 

app.use(cookieSession({
  key: cookieKey,
  secret: cookieSecret,
  maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 hour (rolling)
  })
);

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  // To update the session expiration time we need to send the new
  // expiration in the response cookie.
  // To send again the response cookie to the client we need to
  // update the session object.
  req.session.fake = Date.now();
  next();
});
```

Indeed, if the session object [does not change](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/1.2.0/index.js#L115), cookie-session v. 1.2.0 does not [set the Set-Cookie header](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/1.2.0/index.js#L224) to send the response cookie to the client.

Comment: Why do we need to set a `fake` session with a new value?

Comment: Edited the response to make it clear why changing the session object is needed.

Comment: So the only way of renewing the cookie is by changing some of its properties? I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed to do it. 24 hours are necessary.